# unable to redirect with this command navigate('/login?redirect=shipping') on react router dom i am using version 6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom

I am following a course in that course instructor wrote

react router dom version 5

```
const checkoutHandler = () => {
history.push('/login?redirect=shipping')
}
```

the above code is working fine in that course video,he is logging in and redirecting to shipping page

now i am using version 6 i changed above code to, i am unable to redirect to shipping

```
   import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

   const navigate=useNavigate();

   const checkoutHandler=()=>{
   navigate('/login?redirect=shipping')
```

}

and i can't understand what this '/login?navigate=shipping' command is doing exactly, why i am not able to rdirect.

MRE

```
        App.js
        <Routes>
        <Route path='/cart' element={<CartScreen/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginScreen/>}/>
        <Route path='/shipping' element={<ShippingScreen/>}/>
        <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen/>} exact/>
        </Routes>
```

CartScreen , Click on Checkout.

```
 const checkoutHandler=()=>{
        navigate('/login?navigate=shipping')
}
```

Takes you to Login page
Fill in Form Hit Login
login screen

```
       const redirect = location.search ? 
        location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'

       useEffect(() => {
       if (localStorage.getItem('userInfo') !== null) {
       navigate(redirect)
       }
       }, [])

        isSuccess && navigate('/')
```

Comment: The code you are using appears fine, if you are using a React function component and hook correctly. Is there any errors in the console? What exactly isn't working as expected? What issue are you observing with the RRDv6 implementation?

Comment: No routes matched location "/login/shipping"

Comment: Ok, seems you need to add your routes then. Have you declared the routes? How, or where, is the app navigating to `"/login/shipping"`? Can you share a [mcve] for us for the router, routes, this component doing the redirect to `"/login"`, the `Login` component, and the shipping page?

Comment: ok i'll share in minutes

Comment: Please add your code to your post, the comments are just about the worst place for code since the formatting is not friendly to code snippets. Can you add the `LoginScreen` component as well?

Comment: i added to post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250043/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-raghuram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that `react-router-dom@6` is capable of both absolute ***and*** relative path routing. The difference is that absolute paths start with a leading `"/"` character while relative paths do not.

The redirect target is `"shipping"` since the queryString is `"?redirect=shipping"`

```
navigate('/login?redirect=shipping');
```

In the `LoginScreen` component the code is accessing the location.search`and getting the`"shipping"` value and attempting to navigate there.

```
const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'

useEffect(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('userInfo') !== null) {
    navigate(redirect); // <-- navigate("shipping")
  }
}, []);
```

The result of this is a relative navigation from the current route path `"/login"` to `"/login/shipping"` since the leading `"/"` is missing.

## Solution

Use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook to access the queryString (*instead of the "hackish" string manipulation*), and navigate correctly to the `"/shipping"` route.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

const redirect = searchParams.get("redirect");

useEffect(() => {
  if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))) {
    navigate(`/${redirect}`); // <-- navigate("/shipping")
  }
}, [redirect]);
```

Answer (score 0):

just change   navigate(redirect);    to   navigate(`/${redirect}`);